# Mongoose and NodeJS: Creating a unique system-generated username

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I want to be able to create a system-generated username that is unique. However, the async nature of the mongoose findOne function is tripping me up.

I have a generateUniqueAccountName function that takes in a proposed username and checks with MongoDB if the proposed username is unique. If it is not unique, then a new name is generated until a unique username is found.

Sounds simple enough but generateUniqueAccountName is exited even before a unique name is found. I tried to use Q (my implementation is not shown here) but couldn't make it work either.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

This is the generateUniqueAccountName function:

```
 /**
 * Returns a unique account name based on proposed name
 * @param {String} proposedName
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName) {

  return Account.findOne({accountName: proposedName})
      .then(function(account) {
        if (account != null) {
          console.log('no can do try again: ' + proposedName);
          proposedName += Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
          generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName);
        } else {
          console.log('proposed name is unique' + proposedName);
        }
        return proposedName;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
      });
 }
```

generateUniqueAccountName is called like so:

```
.then(function(newAccount) {
   // Next generate a unique account name
   console.log('Generating unique account name ...');
   let proposedName = (accounts[i].acctFName + accounts[i].acctLName)
                         .replace(/\s/g, '');

   return generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName.toLowerCase())
            .then(function(accountName) {
               console.log('the unique name is ' + accountName);
               newAccount.accountName = accountName;
               return newAccount;
             })
            .catch(function(err) {
               throw err;
             });
})
.then(saving_part);
```

This is a sample output:

```
Generating unique account name ...
no can do try again: teylim
no can do try again: michaelalee
no can do try again: joeykwa
the unique name is teylim86
the unique name is michaelalee72
the unique name is joeykwa91
no can do try again: trishalee
the unique name is trishalee7
proposed name: michaelalee72 is unique
proposed name: joeykwa91 is unique
no can do try again: teylim86
no can do try again: trishalee7
proposed name: teylim8641 is unique
proposed name: trishalee734 is unique
Saving account trishalee7
```

Looking at trishalee, as you can see, the system tries to save the username trishalee7 even though as the log has shown trishalee7 is not a unique name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All what you need to do is to add `return` statement before `generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName)`:

```
function generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName) {
  return Account
    .findOne({accountName: proposedName})
    .then(function(account) {
      if (account) {
        console.log('no can do try again: ' + proposedName);
        proposedName += Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        return generateUniqueAccountName(proposedName); // <== return statement here
      }
      console.log('proposed name is unique' + proposedName);
      return proposedName;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! That was a quick response and, more importantly, solved the problem! Thanks @alexmac.